# I keep getting Out of Line Definition errors when it's copied and pasted?

Tags: c++, qt

This class is a model(DBO) class for a new C++ project I'm doing using QT.  I started coding then went back to create an ERD.  I went back then today after finishing the ERD to code and after finishing the class definitions (Header files), went through for just this file so far to define/implement the methods in the CPP file.  I keep getting Out of Line Definition.  But the methods are copied and pasted from the Header file - I know C++ well but have never had this issue and maybe there's a symbol there that shouldn't be - I have vision issues so it could be somethings' there I don't see and catch.  The header file is:

```
#include "Artist.h"
#include<QDate>
#include<QList>
#include<QString>

#pragma once

namespace net
{
    namespace draconia
    {
        class Media
        {
            unsigned muiMediaId;
            QDate mDtRelease;
            QList<Artist> mLstArtists;
            QString msFilePath, msName;
        protected:
            QList<Artist> getArtistsInternal() const;
            void setArtists(const QList<Artist> &lstArtists);
        public:
            Media();
            Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const QDate &dtRelease);
            Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const unsigned muiReleaseYear);
            Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const QDate &dtRelease, const QString &sFilePath);
            Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const unsigned uiReleaseYear, const QString &sFilePath);
            Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const QDate &dtRelease, const QList<Artist> &lstArtists);
            Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const unsigned uiReleaseYear, const QList<Artist> &lstArtists);
            Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const QDate &dtRelease, const QString &sFilePath, const QList<Artist> &lstArtists);
            Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const unsigned uiReleaseYear, const QString &sFilePath, const QList<Artist> &lstArtists);
            Media(const Media &refCopy);
            virtual ~Media() = 0;

            void addArtist(const Artist &refArtist);
            const QList<Artist> getArtists() const;
            QString &getFilePath() const;
            unsigned getMediaId() const;
            QString getName() const;
            QDate getReleaseDate() const;
            bool removeArtist(const Artist &refArtist);
            void removeArtist(const unsigned uiIndex);
            void setFilePath(const QString &sFilePath);
            void setMediaId(const unsigned uiMediaId);
            void setName(const QString &sName);
            void setReleaseDate(const QDate &dtRelease);
            void setReleaseDate(const unsigned uiReleaseYear);
        };
    }
}
```

and the CPP file is:

```
#include "Media.h"

using namespace net::draconia;

QList<Artist> Media::getArtistsInternal() const
{
    return(mLstArtists);
}

void Media::setArtists(const QList<Artist> &lstArtists)
{
    mLstArtists.clear();
    mLstArtists.append(lstArtists);
}

Media::Media()
    : muiMediaId(0)
{ }

Media::Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const QDate &dtRelease)
    : muiMediaId(uiMediaId)
    , mDtRelease(dtRelease)
    , msName(sName)
{ }

Media::Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const unsigned uiReleaseYear)
    : muiMediaId(uiMediaId)
    , mDtRelease(QDate(static_cast<int>(uiReleaseYear), 1, 1))
    , msName(sName)
{ }

Media::Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const QDate &dtRelease, const QString &sFilePath)
    : muiMediaId(uiMediaId)
    , mDtRelease(dtRelease)
    , msFilePath(sFilePath), msName(sName)
{ }

Media::Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const unsigned uiReleaseYear, const QString &sFilePath)
    : muiMediaId(uiMediaId)
    , mDtRelease(QDate(static_cast<int>(uiReleaseYear), 1, 1))
    , msFilePath(sFilePath), msName(sName)
{ }

Media::Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const QDate &dtRelease, const QList<Artist> &lstArtists)
    : muiMediaId(uiMediaId)
    , mDtRelease(dtRelease)
    , msName(sName)
{
    setArtists(lstArtists);
}

Media::Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const unsigned uiReleaseYear, const QList<Artist> &lstArtists)
    : muiMediaId(uiMediaId)
    , mDtRelease(QDate(static_cast<int>(uiReleaseYear), 1, 1))
    , msName(sName)
{
    setArtists(lstArtists);
}

Media::Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const QDate &dtRelease, const QString &sFilePath, const QList<Artist> &lstArtists)
    : muiMediaId(uiMediaId)
    , mDtRelease(dtRelease)
    , msFilePath(sFilePath), msName(sName)
{
    setArtists(lstArtists);
}

Media::Media(const unsigned uiMediaId, const QString &sName, const unsigned uiReleaseYear, const QString &sFilePath, const QList<Artist> &lstArtists)
    : muiMediaId(uiMediaId)
    , mDtRelease(QDate(static_cast<int>(uiReleaseYear), 1, 1))
    , msFilePath(sFilePath), msName(sName)
{
    setArtists(lstArtists);
}

Media::Media(const Media &refCopy)
    : muiMediaId(refCopy.getMediaId())
    , mDtRelease(refCopy.getReleaseDate())
    , msFilePath(refCopy.getFilePath())
    , msName(refCopy.getName())
{
    setArtists(refCopy.getArtists());
}


void Media::addArtist(const Artist &refArtist)
{
    getArtistsInternal().append(refArtist);
}

const QList<Artist> Media::getArtists() const
{
    return(getArtistsInternal());
}

QString &Media::getFilePath() const
{
    return(msFilePath);
}

unsigned Media::getMediaId() const
{
    return(muiMediaId);
}

QString Media::getName() const
{
    return(msName);
}

QDate Media::getReleaseDate() const
{
    return(mDtRelease);
}

bool Media::removeArtist(const Artist &refArtist)
{
    return(getArtistsInternal().removeOne(refArtist));
}

void Media::removeArtist(const unsigned uiIndex)
{
    getArtistsInternal().removeAt(uiIndex);
}

void Media::setFilePath(const QString &sFilePath)
{
    msFilePath = sFilePath;
}

void Media::setMediaId(const unsigned uiMediaId)
{
    muiMediaId = uiMediaId;
}

void Media::setName(const QString &sName)
{
    msName = sName;
}

void Media::setReleaseDate(const QDate &dtRelease)
{
    mDtRelease = dtRelease;
}

void Media::setReleaseDate(const unsigned uiReleaseYear)
{
    mDtRelease = QDate(static_cast<int>(uiReleaseYear), 1, 1);
}
```

The errors first happen on the 2nd function in the CPP file setArtists() - For whatever reason when manually typing it in, it thinks that lstArtist is a reference to int but yet the getArtists() and getArtistsInternal() works.  After that, it happens on the constructor definitions that have lstArtists as a parameter - and the first removeArtist() (with the actual reference to Artist as a parameter).

I don't know if maybe I'm misusing QList or something because it seems to be only on functions that use the QList.  If I need to, I can paste the class definition (header file) for Artist but I don't see it as necessary.

This couldn't be because of the #pragma once I put at the top, could it?  QT seems to start all class files with #ifndef and #define and ending it with #endif - but that was causing other problems for me where other classes had references to parent objects and such and the parent then had a list of the children.

It seems to be satisfied when I make those functions (about which it complains) inline in the header file but it doesn't like them in the CPP file and I don't #include QList in the CPP file because it's included in the header file already.

Any thoughts?

P.S. If you want to see it in a different light, you can check it out from: https://github.com/sfulmer/MediaDB and the files are Media.h and Media.cpp.

Comment: This is way too much description and not nearly enough actual details for someone to help you.   No one wants to read a novel about why you went through some process to get where you are.   Post the minimal code to reproduce the problem and the exact error message you are getting and delete all the other stuff.  It's important to understand that when you don't understand what's going on, your interpretation of what's going on isn't really very useful - usually people don't share the necessary information because they've assumed that it's not relevant even though they don't understand what's up

Comment: *I keep getting Out of Line Definition.* -- Is this a real compiler error?  If so, you should post it.  That "error" sounds more like a message coming from an IDE or third-party syntax checker (i.e. Intellisense), and not an actual compiler error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the member functions like `::removeArtist`, because `::getArtistsInternal` is returning a copy not a reference, so the member data won't be modified.

Comment: Well that was another bug I just noticed and now fixed in my code - it's supposed to return a reference but wasn't - Media as you may have seen is an abstract class - that's to be used as a base so I haven't been able to use/test it yet.  I figured out my problem though - The #pragma once line I think has to be first in the file - Once I moved that all the errors vanished.  Thanks for viewing/responding though.

Comment: Sir - this IS the minimum amount of code to express the problem - If I KNEW the problem was not the code but the pragma line I wouldn't have posted here in the first place.  Any problem that would be posted anywhere on this site so simple as just a few lines of code are simple enough for me to resolve on my own in less than a minute.  Anytime someone posts something it should be because they went through a process to try to figure it out themselves or else they're lazy and are just looking for hand outs - I've never looked for hand outs and wouldn't answer a question for someone like that.

Comment: @SethD.Fulmer -- The way you solve these issues is to comment out everything, compile, and confirm there are no errors.  Then reintroduce code, compiling each time, until the compiler error is duplicated.  Did you do that?  If not, that is how it's done in the real world, regardless of the size of the program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I had already commented & done my own debugging already - I've been prog, for over 20 years in a lot of languages incl, C++ & Java - I'm a Sr Lvl Full Stack developer in my job & this was for my personal project.  I know damn well how to debug something.  When everything else's considered & the bug still remains I come here - or Quora but I hate people who ask prog questions on Quora so I won't be one myself.  This WAS the least amount of code that still demonstrated the problem.  I know exactly what I'm doing with debugging problems - I just don't have any C++ colleagues.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out my problem - The #pragma once line I think has to be first in the file - Once I moved that all the errors vanished.